# Android:Load a Scaled Down Image into Memory

Tags: android

I used to use BitmapFactory.Options, inSampleSize and inJustDecodeBounds to load a scaled image in memory and not the sample Image...`Is this method load a scaled image in memory?

```
public void ScaledBitmap() {
    Bitmap bMap;
    ImageView iv;
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=4;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
    bMap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.my_image,options);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

Comment: what you exactly wanted to ask ?

Comment: I wanted to ask if with this code the image from Resources is loaded resized/scaled in memory and not the normal Size... I ask why i try to find solutions about Out of Memory Error... Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;`. This means that the decoded bitmap will be null. So bMap will be null.

**UPDATE**: When you give `inJustDecodeBounds=true` and decode the resource, you won't get any bitmap. This option is used only to get the real width and height of the image resource without decoding the image. Using this width and height, you can calculate the `inSampleSize`. Once you have calculated that, set the inSampleSize and set `inJustDecodeBounds=false` and decode the resource again. Now you will get the correct scaled bitmap.

You will find more info on how to effectively scale a bitmap here : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Without `options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;` if i use only `inSampleSize` the image is loaded scaled? I saw the guide for bitmaps on Android Developer but i get confused a little...

Comment: @VagelisAgelousis Is this not the answer  you are looking for? Any issues?

Comment: Yeah i don't understand the android documentation very well and i want to ask you @Henry for something more. If i specify the `options.inSampleSize` for example to 6 for image from res/drawable it will be loaded resized in memory or operates like with `bMapScaled.createScaledBitmap(bMap,width,height,true);` which load firstly the full size of image... Thanks in Advace

Comment: when you set `options.inSampleSize = 6` and then decode the bitmap, you will not load the full size, but the reduced size. This is why we use the BitmapOptions.

Comment: It is okay then to do it when the image dimensions are known? I have read and other methods in order to decrease the memory like `options.inPreferredConfig` and `options.inPurgeable=true` but the last are deprecated for lollipop and above i think...

Comment: The right way of doing it is via the inSampleSize. You will calculate the inSampleSize based on the known image dimensions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help... What is the difference if i calculate the `inSampleSize` with the method provided by android documentation or i specify alone `inSampleSize` for example 6,8 etc...

Comment: if you use the method that is specified in the documentation, you will get the correct optimal value of the inSampleSize, and thus the image will be of correct resolution. If you specify your own inSampleSize, then you might end up with improper resolution.